# настроить длину ответа porfirevich с помощью requests

Tags: python, requests, post

я его получаю, но ответы очень короткие, а иногда он даже обрывается на полуслове. Не обращайте внимания на остальной код.

```
@bot.command()
async def porf(ctx: commands.Context, *, req: str = None):
    if req == None:
        return await ctx.channel.send("Enter request!")
    
    data = {'prompt': req}

    r = requests.post(f'https://pelevin.gpt.dobro.ai/generate/', json=data)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{req}{r.json()['replies'][0]}")
```

Comment: С помощью параметра `length` вот так: `data = {'prompt': req, "length":100}`

Comment: Спасибо большое <3